# VMWare Workstation 9.0.2 for Linux build 1031769. Failed to execute child process "@@BINARY@@"

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, vmware

I got the error after installing VMWare Workstation 9.0.2. Here is the output the `uname -a` command.

```
Linux dmitriev-pc 3.5.0-34-generic #55~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 7 16:25:50 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Ubuntu version is Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS.

Did anybody manage to solve it? The sole advice I read was to reinstall `VMWare Workstation` but it didn't work for me.

**Edit #1.**

```
/etc/vmware-installer/components/vmware-workstation/9.0.2/vmware-workstation.py:      self.RunCommand('sed', '-e', 's,@@BINARY@@,%s,g' % binary, '-i', launcher)
Binary file /etc/vmware-installer/components/vmware-workstation/9.0.2/vmware-workstation.pyc matches
/etc/vmware-installer/components/vmware-network-editor-ui/9.0.2/vmware-network-editor-ui.py:      self.RunCommand('sed', '-e', 's,@@BINARY@@,%s,g' % binary, '-i', launcher)
Binary file /etc/vmware-installer/components/vmware-network-editor-ui/9.0.2/vmware-network-editor-ui.pyc matches
Binary file /etc/vmware-installer/components/vmware-player-app/5.0.2/vmware-player-app.pyc matches
/etc/vmware-installer/components/vmware-player-app/5.0.2/vmware-player-app.py:      self.RunCommand('sed', '-e', 's,@@BINARY@@,%s,g' % binary, '-i', launcher)
```

**Solved**

There is a strange suffix `%F` in the `/usr/share/applications/vmware-workstation.desktop` file. I didn't find what it could mean on the `man vmware` man page.

`Exec=/usr/bin/vmware %F`

If I run `vmware` via my command line, it runs with no errors.

[image: The screenshot]

Comment: Looks like a bug in the installer. Try to `grep -r "@@BINARY@@" /etc/ /usr/bin` (I'm not sure where VMWare Workstation is installed). This should show you the file that has the string in it. Then you can edit and fix it, and submit a bug report.

Comment: @danielkullmann, you are right. Please take a look at Edit #1. But I am afraid I can't fix the error by myself and submit the bug report because I don't know Python.

Comment: The files you found are just the installer scripts that should replace @@BINARY@@ with real values.

Comment: @danielkullmann, I've found a solution

Comment: The %F is part of the .desktop file specification: http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s06.html. So that's not your problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the way I was able to get it to work was to make a copy of the .desktop file (`vmware-workstation.desktop`) located at `/usr/share/applications` and save it on my desktop.

Then change the permissions so it can be executed and run it from the desktop.

```
$ cp /usr/share/applications/vmware-workstation.desktop ./Desktop/vmware-workstation.desktop
$ cd ./Desktop
$ sudo chmod +x vmware-workstation.desktop
$ ./vmware-workstation.desktop
```

Fixed some spelling